# Scrollview inside viewpager scroll vertical not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview

Below is my code but its not working properly, want a viewpager with scrollview in all fragment. Scrolling of the scrollview is not working,facing problem from last 2 hrs and not getting a solution.Please help me its urgent.Not able to solve this issue i tried adding nested scrollview but it is also not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_myjeenees"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarShuffle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Shuffle Money"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="UserName"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="May 15,Birthday" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_forward" />
</LinearLayout>


<com.android.jeenees.utils.CustomScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/shufflePager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</com.android.jeenees.utils.CustomScrollView>
<!--</LinearLayout>-->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_tick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_back" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/firstwish"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="IPhone 5s" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/costfirst"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rs 5300/32777" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekfirst"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:maxHeight="10dp"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_draw"
                        android:splitTrack="false"
                        android:thumb="@mipmap/ic_thumb"></SeekBar>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/secondwish"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="IPhone 5s" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/costsecond"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rs 5300/32777" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seeksecond"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:maxHeight="10dp"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_draw"
                        android:splitTrack="false"
                        android:thumb="@mipmap/ic_thumb"></SeekBar>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/thirdwish"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="IPhone 5s" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/costthird"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rs 5300/32777" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekthird"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:maxHeight="10dp"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_draw_red"
                        android:splitTrack="false"
                        android:thumb="@mipmap/ic_red_thumb"></SeekBar>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Rs 1700"
            android:textSize="25sp" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Released Money"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_actin_add"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Top Up"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why have you added `ViewPager` in `ScrollView` when you already have `ScrollView` in your `Fragment` layout?

Comment: that one i corrected :)  but still the scroll is not working:)

Comment: i am making the parent layout as a scrollview but still it is not working

Comment: Then update your code please and post a picture (if possible) so I can guide you better

Comment: Oops. You removed `ScrollView` from the child I would never recommend that. Instead, remove the `CustomScrollView` from parent and use android default `ScrollView` in child layout. It should work!

Comment: nah ! dear normal scrollview is not working i tried alot actually first use my code and see the layout in your android studios please then u will know

Comment: u know any site on which i can upload the screen shot so dat u can view and know what is the exact problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99117/discussion-between-rehan-and-user3475052).

Answer (score 1):

Each view take parent event first if your view pager is swipe horizonatly for change the page tab than you can not use horizonatl scroll in child fragment . It is not write practice you can arrange your page content as vertical and use vertical scroll view.
Or second option you will have to disable swipe event for view pager and only tab click is uesd to change page than you can use horizontal scroll view.