# ScrollView Inside ViewPager Not Working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollview

i have an activity ViewPager and which have Tabbed Childs. The childs with recycler View do Scroll. Although When i create a simple fragment with scroll view it does not work.
here is the main activity fragment -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabbed_main"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/vp_horizontal_ntb"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<com.gigamole.navigationtabbar.ntb.NavigationTabBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/ntb_horizontal"
    app:ntb_badge_size="12sp"
    app:ntb_badge_bg_color="#ffff0000"
    app:ntb_badge_gravity="top"
    app:ntb_badge_position="right"
    app:ntb_badge_title_color="#ffffffff"
    app:ntb_badge_use_typeface="true"
    app:ntb_badged="true"
    app:ntb_animation_duration="400" />
</LinearLayout>


<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:id="@+id/create_new_button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white_add"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
    fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">
    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_create_post"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white_add"
        fab:fab_title="Create New Post"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>
    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_create_new_message"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white_add"
        fab:fab_title="Write New Message"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_insert_comment_black_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>
    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_upload_new_album"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white_add"
        fab:fab_title="Upload New Album"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_black_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>
</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is the child fragment -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingRight="22dp"
android:paddingLeft="22dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:scrollbars="none"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/main_background_blured"
android:isScrollContainer="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">
        <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.RailwayRegular
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SETTINGS"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/main_logo_color"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.TrilliumWebLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Security"
                android:textColor="@color/half_black"
                android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:src="@color/half_black"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.RailwayLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Change Password"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="@color/main_logo_color"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:src="@color/edward"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.RailwayLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Change Default Email"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="@color/main_logo_color"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.TrilliumWebLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="General"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:src="@color/half_black"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.RailwayLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Change Name"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="@color/main_logo_color"/>
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.TrilliumWebLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SomeName"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:src="@color/edward"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.RailwayLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Change Phone Number"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="@color/main_logo_color"/>
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.TrilliumWebLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="phone number"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.TrilliumWebLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Blocking"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:src="@color/half_black"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">
                <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.RailwayLight
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Blocking"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/main_logo_color" />
                <com.cengalabs.flatui.views.FlatToggleButton
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    xmlns:flat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    flat:fl_space="14dp"
                    flat:fl_cornerRadius="14dp"
                    flat:fl_size="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    flat:fl_theme="@array/grass"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:src="@color/edward"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.RailwayLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Block List"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="@color/main_logo_color"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.TrilliumWebLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Language"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:src="@color/half_black"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.RailwayLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Change Language"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="@color/main_logo_color"/>
            <com.evolutionstudios.atmiyo.customfonts.TrilliumWebLight
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SomeLanguage"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i have tried with a lot of answers here like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860588/scrollview-inside-viewpager-not-scrolling), [here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157268/scrollview-inside-a-fragment-with-tablayout-is-not-scrolling-why/35180360#35180360) and [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491117/scrollview-inside-viewpager-scroll-vertical-not-working)

as someone pointed to use NestedScrollView instead ScrollView and i tried that too, but with no luck. Any solutions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to solve a similar vertical scrolling problem in my ViewPager doing the following:

1. I created a separate layout (content_event) with ViewPager:

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/viewPagerActivEvent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. And created NestedScrollView enclosing preceding layout with "android:fillViewport" set to true:

   ```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

       <include layout="@layout/content_event" >

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
   ```

Maybe it's not quite right but worked for me:)